# Stimulsoft code based variables won't show their value

Tags: vb.net, variables, report, reporting, stimulsoft

I´m losing my mind here, I've tried every example I've found online and still can't get it to work, this is the way im creating the variable on the code that generates the report, I'm working on a .NET application:

```
report.Dictionary.Variables.Add(New Stimulsoft.Report.Dictionary.StiVariable("test",""))
report("test") = "ANYTHING"
```

While it does show me the created variables on the Stimuloft gui, it contains absolutely nothing, any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: I need to see more code before this.

Comment: Well what exactly? The rest of my code has either very little or nothing to do with this, and the related code is just the one that loads the form, and im doing this after I load the dictionary, it really has no more depth than this..

Answer (score 0):

You should use next code to set value of variable:

```
report.Dictionary.Variables("test").Value = "ANYTHING"
```

The code that you use will work after calling report.Compile() method only.